# Given a series onverges does the series of the power of former series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

given   $[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x ]$ converges, does the series of its power converge (given $x^n$ > 0)? $[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n]$ ?

So far, I know that $[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/x]$ diverges and $[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/x^k]$ converges with k > 1.

It would be great if you help me solve this. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

No. For example $$\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$ converges, but when you square the general term, you obtain $$\sum \frac{1}{n}$$ which diverges.

If the general term $x_n$ is non-negative, however, this would be true. Indeed, if $\sum x_n$ converges, then $(x_n)$ tends to $0$, and so for all $k > 1$, you have $x_n^k = o(x_n)$, so the series $\sum x_n^k$ also converges.